# How to convert nested lists into nested tuples in Python

Tags: python, list, tuples, list-comprehension

How can I tranform this 3D list to tuple?

```
[[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [100]]
```

I use this code :

```
tuple(tuple(tuple(j for j in i) for i in x))
```

but I still have [] in the result

```
(([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]),
 ([0, 0], [0, 0]),
 (100,))
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Just add another tuple comprehension `tuple(tuple(tuple(tuple(k for k in j) for j in i) for i in x))`. This will cause an error for your example because the last element `100` is not nested correctly for it to be a 3D list.

Comment: @Cubed Still this is not a generalised approach. If you have more than 3 nested levels what you suggest will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding is that you just want to convert nested lists into nested tuples. If this is what you need, then you'll probably need to come up with a **recursive approach** to deal with cases where you have an arbitrary number of nested lists.

---

For example,

```
def nested_list_to_tuple_recur(nested_list):
    return tuple(
      nested_list_to_tuple_recur(l) if isinstance(l, list) 
      else l for l in nested_list
    )
```

And finally call the function:

```
nested_list_to_tuple_recur(x)
```

And the output will be

```
(((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)),
 ((0, 0), (0, 0)),
 (100,))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap 100 into another list, otherwise there are on different levels, some are packed in 2 list some only in one. If you fix that you can try this:

```
l = [[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0], [0, 0]],
 [[100]]]


tuple(tuple(x) for y in l for x in y)

# ((0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
#  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
#  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
#  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
#  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
#  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
#  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
#  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
#  (0, 0),
#  (0, 0),
#  (100,))
```